# Where is <boost/lexcal_cast.hpp>?

Tags: c++, boost

I just downloaded boost 1.4.7.0, but compiler can't find boost/lexcal_cast.hpp

I am trying to convert a string to number using boost.
Sample code:

```
#include <boost/lexcal_cast.hpp>

// ...
int i = 42;
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
int j = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s)
```

Where can I find that??? Do I need additional library beside the standard?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you have boost installed?

Comment: C:\boost_1_47_0.  Under this directory I have \boost\, \docs\, \libs\, \more\, \status\, and \tools\. Basically, default setup after the extract. Thanks GWW

Comment: @GWW nvm. Marcelo found my silly mistake. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `<boost/lexical_cast.hpp>`? You're missing an ‘i’.

Comment: Thanks!!!! DAMN. I copied this from a thread, and I have been searching for two days. What a silly mistake... Thanks.. lol